# Can we dockerize Azure functions?

Tags: docker, azure, docker-for-windows

I want to know whether we can dockerize Azure Functions?
As I know that dockerization needs client-server kind of application.
I have some azure functions which are event/timer driven. I want to dockerize this.
Need help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to MSFT you can run Azure Fucntion v2 onpremise as well.

You may find tutorial how to containerize Azure Function on:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you [edit] your answer to include the relevant parts on containerising Docker from the link you posted? Cheers!